# React - Show element with click, and hide it by click outside of it and on it

Tags: reactjs, toggle, hide, show, use-ref

I have to build notification bell with with notification badge (for number of notifications).
When I click on bell, notification badge dissappears, and dropdown list with notifications is shown.
That part is done.

Next, when I click on that dropdown notification list or out of it (anywhere on page) list is closed.
That is also ok.

But when dropdown list is open and I click on notification bell (or its wrapper) list should be closed (hidden again). And that is not working. Also maybe it would be good that notification badge disappears then because list was opened, but toggle by clicking on bell is my main problem here.

Any help is welcome!
Here is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Effect } from 'react-notification-badge';
import NotificationBadge from 'react-notification-badge/lib/components/NotificationBadge';
import logoIcon from '../images/logo.svg';
import notificationIcon from '../images/notification.svg';

const TopBar = () => {
  const [notifBadgeIsShown, setNotifBadgeShown] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);
  });

  const refOne = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (!refOne.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setNotifBadgeShown(false);
    }
    if (refOne.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setNotifBadgeShown(false);
    }
  };

  const notifications = ['Notification 1', 'Notification 2'];

  let listItems = notifications.map((number) => (
    <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="top-bar">
      <img className="logo-icon" src={logoIcon} alt="Logo icon" />
      <div
        className="notification-wrapper"
        onClick={() =>
          notifBadgeIsShown === false
            ? setNotifBadgeShown(true)
            : setNotifBadgeShown(false)
        }
      >
        {!notifBadgeIsShown ? (
          <NotificationBadge
            className="notif-badge"
            count={notifications.length}
            effect={Effect.SCALE}
          />
        ) : null}
        {notifBadgeIsShown ? <div className="dropdown">{listItems}</div> : null}

        <img
          className="notification-icon"
          src={notificationIcon}
          alt="Notification icon"
          ref={refOne}
        />
      </div>
    </div>

  );
};

export default TopBar;
```

I have try to do this with useRef, but still no desired result...

Comment: Hey Goran, please set blank array inside useEffect else you may face infinite look.
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);
  },[]);
and then show the result..
Thanks

Comment: @VarunKaklia Thanks for advice, I added [] as you said, but still no desired result...
I thing that problem is somewhere in onClick event in ".notification-wrapper" div or something with useRef need do be different...

Comment: Then change onClick function-
        onClick={() =>setNotifBadgeShown(!notifBadgeIsShown)
        }
This will change setNotificationBage boolean value from false to true and true to false